# What "high-tech fission-powered mission" almost "killed" New Horizons?

Tags: new-horizons, nuclear, electric-propulsion

When reading the Discover Magazine article [How New Horizons Survived the 40-Year-Glitch and Made it to Pluto](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/outthere/2015/07/10/how-new-horizons-survived-the-40-year-glitch-and-made-it-to-pluto) while writing [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19042/12102) I saw "...the new NASA administrator tried to kill New Horizons in favor of a high-tech fission-powered mission." (see below for the context):

What was the high-tech fission-powered mission? Does it have a name - and is it described somewhere?

> The missions had such hopeful names: Pluto 350, Pluto Fast Flyby, Pluto Express. Finally, Stern came up with the winning concept, New Horizons. His final proposal was due one week after 9/11, while the offices of the Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Lab (which operates the mission) were still shut. Stern completed the proposal and NASA approved it.
>
> The following year, the new NASA administrator tried to kill New Horizons in favor of a high-tech fission-powered mission. He failed, and New Horizons survived. One benefit of its long, difficult competition is that Stern and the mission engineers came up with a relatively inexpensive, flyweight spacecraft. New Horizons weighs about half as much as Voyager 1, and in real dollars costs roughly one-third as much. Placing a lightweight probe atop a large Atlas V rocket yielded the fastest object ever launched when New Horizons took off in 2006...

Comment: Some info here (sorry for long link): https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQy6D-5q7QAhWEjlQKHcw_CKgQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ferps.spacegrant.org%2Fuploads%2Fimages%2Fimages%2Fiepc_articledownload_1988-2007%2F1993index%2FIEPC1993-200.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGBeCi4A-ulb0XPHP0GYWj6hYsrjQ&sig2=p3Ro36Z-_03UEEOBFoBUvg  Best info might be the list of papers cited

Comment: The paper is interesting - actually I suppose sooner or later nuclear electric propulsion will be tested, this was a little ahead of its time perhaps. It seems to be called NEPSTP (Nuclear Electric Propulsion Space Test Program), but I would have called it **U2Pu** (Uranium to Pluto). Thanks!! (this link also works: http://erps.spacegrant.org/uploads/images/images/iepc_articledownload_1988-2007/1993index/IEPC1993-200.pdf)

Comment: @OrganicMarble would you be interested in posting a short answer based on the links in these comments?

Comment: I'll try to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "fission mission" was called the Pluto Fast Flyby. It was two small RTG powered spacecraft, and "found a ready ally in then NASA administrator D. Goldin".  The "high tech" part of your quote may refer to the "highly miniaturized (then nonexistent)" instruments.

> However,  in  the  late  spring  of  1992,  a  new,  more  radical
>   mission concept called Pluto Fast Flyby (PFF) was introduced by the
>   Jet Propulsion Laboratory (JPL) as a “faster, better,  cheaper” 
>   alternative   to  the  Mariner  Mark  II  and Pluto-350  Pluto 
>   mission  concepts.  As  initially  conceived, PFF  was  to  weigh 
>   just  35–50  kg  and  carry  only  7  kg  of highly miniaturized (then
>   nonexistent) instruments, and fly two spacecraft to Pluto for less than \$ 500M. PFF found a ready ally in  then  NASA  Administrator  D.  Goldin,  who
>   directed  all Pluto-350  and  Mariner  Mark  II  work  to  cease  in 
>   favor  of PFF.  PFF  would  have  launched  its  two  flyby 
>   spacecraft on  Titan  IV-Centaur  launchers;  these  low-mass 
>   spacecraft would have shaved the Pluto-350 and Mariner Mark II flight
>   times  from  12–15  years  down  to  7  or  8  years.  Like  Mariner
>   Mark  II  and  Pluto-350,  PFF  involved  RTG  power  and Jupiter 
>   gravity  assists  (JGAs).  The  heavier  missions  also involved Earth
>   and Venus gravity assists on the way to Jupiter.  All  these 
>   mission  concepts  were  developed  by  JPL mission study teams.
>   Shortly  after  PFF  was  introduced,  however,  it  ran  into
>   problems. One was mass growth, which quickly escalated the  flight 
>   system  to  ~140  kg  with  no  increase  in  science payload  mass. 
>   A  second  issue  involved  cost  increases, largely due to a broad
>   move within NASA to include launch vehicle costs in mission cost
>   estimates; since two Titan IV launchers alone cost over \$800M, this
>   pushed PFF to well over  \$1B.  A  third  issue  was  the  turmoil 
>   introduced  into NASA’s planetary program by the loss of the Mars
>   Observer in 1993. These events caused PFF to lose favor at NASA, and
>   the concept never made it into the development phase. Nevertheless,
>   during 1994–1995 PFF did solicit, select, and fund the
>   breadboard/brassboard development of a suite of miniaturized imagers,
>   spectrometers, and radio science and plasma instruments, whose
>   successors  would ultimately become the science payload on NH.

[Source](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/~mbrown/out/kbbook/Chapters/Weaver_NewHorizons.pdf)

Comment: The source is from the book [The Solar System Beyond Neptune](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/books/ssbn2008/download.html)?

Comment: Looks like it. There's a top level directory here http://web.gps.caltech.edu/~mbrown/out/kbbook/  There's a warning about copying the book at your link.  Not sure why this Cal Tech guy has it on his website....  But your link is weird. "Downloading of a chapter by anyone other than an author of that chapter is expressly prohibited." That sounds as useful as the FBI warning on VHS tapes.